# How to simple change checkmark in TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

In my application, in storyboard, I have a screen with a lot of Table View Cells.

For example, in first two of them, I need to move checkmarks, when user touches one of them (make a select).

[image]

Is there are an easy way to do it, for example, like outlet connection?
Or how it is possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Apple's documentation on [managing selections in UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html).  Basically, you'll coordinate the accessory views of the previously selected cell (remove the checkmark accessory) and currently selected cell (add the checkmark accessory) in your table view's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Here's a rough implementation, assuming you have an array of available `taskTypes`, and a property for the `currentTaskType` selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    NSInteger taskTypeIndex = [taskTypes indexOfObject:[self currentTaskType]];

    if ( taskTypeIndex == [indexPath row] )
    {
        return;
    }

    NSIndexPath     *oldIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:taskTypeIndex inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *newCell      = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *oldCell      = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];

    if ( [newCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone )
    {
        [newCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self setCurrentTaskType:[taskTypes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    }

    if ( [oldCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark )
    {
        [oldCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
}
```